# Keping history in Winforms C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

I have an application made in winform using C++ (developed in VS 2010). The GUIs have certain text fields, radio button, check boxes etc. To operate the software one has to fill in these fields/buttons/boxes etc.

There are roughly such 50 different GUIs, having roughly 20 fields in each one.

I want that after the application is closed, and restarted, most recent parameters in this fields automatically fill in, so the user do not need to re-enter all those values again.

What is the easiest and simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is best solved using MVC pattern where the Model contains the data that was filled. The view contains the way it will be presented(such as in Winforms) And lastly the controller which besides doing business logic will need to do some work (for saving the state).

I prefer using serialization for this. You can serialize the model fields and read them back(fields that are necessary only).

If you don't like serialization you can try writing to INI files that will be easy to modify.

Thirdly you can use a database `mdf` file to store the state.

But to do all this well you will need to modify the App to use MVC architecture.

Comment: @gpuguy write the state to MDF file then -- that will be my strategy at such a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Registry with

WindowsFormName (subkey)
              ---------> ControlName (subkey)
                               -----------------> ControlValue (subkey)

When the Form is Closing you save the values for each control in the Registry

When the Form is Loading you read the values

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with a quick and dirty solution you can try this:

Implement a save mechanism:

1. Iterate to all the form controls (recursively if there are panels or
   other containers)
2. If the control is edit (or other type that holds
   data) save the control text together with his name
3. Store the name,
   value pairs (INI file for example)

Implement a load mechanism. This assumes that there are no dependencies between values (If there are automated computed fields do not save them)

1. Load the values from the storage (if you choose files the file name can be the form name)
2. iterate to all the form controls and if you find its name in loaded data set the value

Once implemented this approach can be used for all the forms and it will cope with adding/removing controls. However if there are business rules maybe is better to use a MVC approach and serialize the model.